# Calling a Sub that Connects to DB from Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm writing a VB.net 2017 Windows Service that looks at SQL and depending on the number of rows, it will create multiple threads. These threads monitor folders and report back to a different table and log the data accordingly. This piece of code has been running for a few years and has been working very well but in the last few days, I've decided to switch it from a console application that runs on start up to a window service and this is my first time writing a windows service.

I've went through and got the code to work but testing was a major pain because I couldn't walk through the code. I made some changes and consolidated some of the duplicate sections. For example, I was writing 4 or 5 different sections of code to either write data to SQL or pull data from SQL. I consolidated these down to only 2 sub routines and the threads continuously use them. Depending on the situation, the program can have between 1-15 threads and when I start activating more threads, I started to run into an issue. I already had try statements in my code from the console app before I ported it and I just put these into a log table when creating the new program and it was complaining that I was trying to Open an "Open connection". Here is an example of one the routines that pulls data from SQL:

```
Public con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Public dsGeneral As New DataSet
Public dc1 As SqlClient.SqlCommand
Public pullGeneral As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Public maxRowsGeneral As Integer

Public Sub PullGeneralSQL(ByVal SQL As String)
    Try
        If (con.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        dsGeneral.Tables.Clear()

        pullGeneral = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con)
        pullGeneral.Fill(dsGeneral, "General")

        maxRowsGeneral = dsGeneral.Tables("General").Rows.Count
    Catch ex As Exception
        Msg(ex.Message, "Error")
        maxRowsGeneral = 0
    End Try

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

I'm also getting errors saying that the connection is already closed as well. I'm assuming that another thread has finished connecting and closed the connection while a thread was in the middle of a task.

My question is, what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Do you only want one thread at a time to have an open database connection? If so then you might want to use `SyncLock` around the code that opens and closes the connection, to restrict it to one thread at a time.  Otherwise, make sure that you're enabling `MultipleActiveResultSets` in your connection string.

Comment: Is there a maximum of 15 threads ?

Comment: jmcihinney - I basically want a thread to open a connection, do it's thing and then close the connection. I was thinking that each thread would be allowed to connect independently and wouldn't cause issues with each other.

Comment: EJD - The threads will scale depending on the amount of folders they need to monitor. This is a program that gets installed on a server and some will have 2 threads and some will have 5 and the most I've setup have 15 but I've programmed it to have no maximum amount (besides the limitation of calling threads into memory).

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue before even though there is connection pooling eventually as you open and close and open and close connections the database ends up throwing errors like you are getting.  In my case it was 600 threads over and over.  Worked for a little while then threw the same types of errors.

The solution for me was to create my own connection pool.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public dsGeneral As New DataSet
    Public dc1 As SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Public pullGeneral As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Public maxRowsGeneral As Integer

    Public Sub PullGeneralSQL(ByVal SQL As String)

        'Get a connection from the list..Thread safe
        'Your thread will wait here until there is a connection to grab.
        'Since your max is 15 the 16++ threads will all wait their turn
        Dim con As SqlClient.SqlConnection = ConnectionManager.WaitForConnection()

        Try
            dsGeneral.Tables.Clear()

            pullGeneral = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con)
            pullGeneral.Fill(dsGeneral, "General")

            maxRowsGeneral = dsGeneral.Tables("General").Rows.Count
        Catch ex As Exception
            Msg(ex.Message, "Error")
            maxRowsGeneral = 0
        End Try

        'Put the connection back into the list
        'Allows another thread to start
        ConnectionManager.ReleaseConnection(con)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ConnectionManager
    Public Shared poolLimit As Integer = 15 'Maximum number of connections to open.
    Public Shared connectionString As String = "PUT YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE"

    'Since this is static it will create 15 connections and add them to the list when the service starts
    Private Shared ConnectionList As New IThreadPool(Of SqlClient.SqlConnection)(Function()
                                                                                     Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)
                                                                                     connection.Open()
                                                                                     Return connection
                                                                                 End Function, poolLimit)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the pool count.
    ''' Purely for information to get the number of connections left in the list
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property PoolCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return ConnectionList.PoolCount
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Waits until there is a free connection in the list
    ''' When there is a free connection grab it and hold it
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function WaitForConnection() As SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Try
            Return ConnectionList.GetObject()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'only during close
            Throw ex
        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Releases the connection.
    ''' Put the connection back into the list.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Sub ReleaseConnection(connection As SqlClient.SqlConnection)
        Try
            ConnectionList.PutObject(connection)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'only during close
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Disposes this instance.
    ''' Make sure to dispose when the service shuts down or your connections will stay active.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Sub Dispose()
        ConnectionList.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class IThreadPool(Of T)
    Private connections As System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection(Of T)
    Private objectGenerator As Func(Of T)

    Public Sub New(objectGenerator As Func(Of T), boundedCapacity As Integer)

        If objectGenerator Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("objectGenerator")
        End If

        connections = New System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection(Of T)(New System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of T)(), boundedCapacity)

        Me.objectGenerator = objectGenerator

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                  If connections.Count < boundedCapacity Then
                                      Parallel.[For](0, boundedCapacity, Function(i)
                                                                             Try
                                                                                 If connections.Count < boundedCapacity Then
                                                                                     connections.Add(Me.objectGenerator())
                                                                                 End If
                                                                             Catch ex As Exception
                                                                                 'only error during close
                                                                             End Try
                                                                         End Function)

                                      Try
                                          While connections.Count < boundedCapacity
                                              connections.Add(Me.objectGenerator())
                                          End While
                                      Catch ex As Exception
                                          'only error during close
                                      End Try
                                  End If
                              End Function)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property PoolCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return If(connections IsNot Nothing, connections.Count, 0)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function GetObject() As T
        Return connections.Take()
    End Function

    Public Sub PutObject(item As T)
        connections.Add(item)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose()
        connections.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your code works beautiiful but instead of "15" I used "1" because I cannot get it to run with "15" connections. I've tried to enable "Mars" but it still did not allow me to get it to run. Basically, I get the first SQL command to run but the program will never come back.

Comment: If it doesn't come back then you are not releasing the connection back to the list of connections or you are using a transaction and the Database is in deadlock.  I use this exact code in a project that opens 600 connections.

Comment: It runs, but if I set the "Pool Limit" to 15 like in you code, the service never truly starts but if I set it to "1". It will start and it will run. It seems like I cannot have more then 1 active connection to the database.

Comment: You can alway write a test project to make 15 connections and see.